# Use Recursion to get Subsets of an array. C++ and Java give me different results

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

For example, given a set like below -

```
S=[1,3]
```

we want to get the list of list with following values:

```
[[],[1],[3],[1,3]]
```

I used C++ with the following code and it worked perfect for me.
However, after I changed it to Java, the code didn't give me right results.

Any help? This is my Java code:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> subsetsRecursive(int[] nums){
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if(nums.length == 0){
        return res;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> itemList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    dfs(res, itemList, 0, nums);

    return res;
}

private static void dfs(List<List<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> temp, int end, int[] nums) {
    if(end == nums.length) {
        res.add(temp);
        return;
    }

    temp.add(nums[end]);
    dfs(res, temp, end+1, nums);
    temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
    dfs(res, temp, end+1, nums);   
}
```

And this is C++:

```
class Solution {
private:
    vector<vector<int> >res;
public:
    vector<vector<int> > subsets(vector<int> &S) {
        res.clear();

        vector<int>tmpres;
        dfs(S, 0, tmpres);
        return res;
    }
    void dfs(vector<int> &S, int iend, vector<int> &tmpres)
    {
        if(iend == S.size())
            {res.push_back(tmpres); return;}

        tmpres.push_back(S[iend]);
        dfs(S, iend+1, tmpres);
        tmpres.pop_back();

        dfs(S, iend+1, tmpres);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting in java?

Comment: good question...an empty list...

Comment: Can you attempt to describe what you're trying to have the program doing, i.e. describing the algorithm you need help with?  You gave only a very small, and specific example.

Comment: What is `i` in Java code?

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin I used recursion to get all the subsets of an array. I tried to be specific as I know the algorithm - the problem is about C++ and Java - same algorithm --so my question is in terms of the provided code, why only C++ works for me not JAVA???

Comment: @soon sorry, typo -- it should be 0

Comment: There may be other, less obvious, typos in the posted code, so please copy-paste the code you ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line
`res.add(temp);` temp is a reference.

You are adding a reference to the same list (itemList) every time you add it.

Try changing it to something list `res.add(new ArrayList(temp));` so that it copies the list instead.

Comment: My bad... so obvious ... Brain stops working after a whole day work... Thank you very much!